# How do I get a server to pass a cookie to a test client running on a different IP

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies, express-session

I have a server running on DigitalOcean at a certain domain. I'm currently working on a web app, and I wanted to have the frontend display locally so I could make changes to it without pushing it to the remote server. Unfortunately, this means I cannot test the frontend because it won't be able to receive cookies from the server, since it's not on the same domain.

I was wondering if there was a way of circumventing this, and if others generally had the same problem.

I am currently using Node.js and Express with express-sessions for my backend, and React for frontend, if that helps.